# RabbitMQ php-amqplib ERROR Connection reset by peer and Broken pipe or closed connection

Tags: php, cakephp, rabbitmq, php-amqplib

After processing the message successfully, the consumer returns error "Error: [PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPConnectionClosedException] Connection reset by peer"

The message takes about 1000 seconds to process

connection_timeout: 2000
read_write_timeout: 2000
keepalive: true
heartbeat: 1000

php version: 7.2.28
php-amqplib version: 2.11
rabbitmq version: 3.9.7
erlang version: 23.3.4.7
cakephp version: 3.6
cakephp-rabbitmq version: 1.0

If I disable the heartbeat, when finishing the message process, it returns "Error: [PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPConnectionClosedException] Broken pipe or closed connection", and sometimes it doesn't return any error, but the consumer no longer receives messages

I can't understand the cause of the problem, but I need the consumer to be able to process long messages

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.